# How to force Verbose Mode in PowerShell binary cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I have some scenarios where I would like to force the verbose switch to ON even if users did not supply the -verbose parameter. Example, some of my Cmlets read their verbosity level from a configuration file.

In a regular Cmdlet (non-binary) I achieve this like so:

```
if ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData['verbose'])
    {
        $VerbosePreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue
    }
    $isInVerboseMode = ($VerbosePreference -eq [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue)
```

Note that the verbosity level is read from the module's PrivateData hash table and applied to the $VerbosityPreference variable.

Question: how would I accomplish the same behavior when developing a binary Cmdlet via C#? Perhaps, a more specific question would be: how do I access VerbosePreference variable inside a C# Cmdlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set PowerShell variables from your binary cmdlet if you derive from `PSCmdlet`:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

public class MyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        this.SessionState.PSVariable.Set("VerbosePreference", ActionPreference.Continue);
    }
}
```

To temporarily enable verbose output in cmdlets I use something like:

```
public class MyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        using var _ = this.EnableVerbose();
        //... cmdlet implementation
    }
}

static class UseVariableExtension
{
    public static IDisposable EnableVerbose(this PSCmdlet cmdlet) => new WithVariableValue(cmdlet, "VerbosePreference", ActionPreference.Continue);

    class WithVariableValue : IDisposable
    {
        readonly PSCmdlet _cmdlet;
        readonly string _variableName;
        readonly object _originalValue;

        public WithVariableValue(PSCmdlet cmdlet, string variableName, object? value)
        {
            _cmdlet = cmdlet;
            _variableName = variableName;
            _originalValue = cmdlet.GetVariableValue(variableName);
            cmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set(variableName, value);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _cmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set(_variableName, _originalValue);
        }
    }
}
```